# A variable in Bash that contains quotation marks and spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, variable

I'm trying the following in a Bash script:

```
MV_PARAMS='"foo 1" "foo 2"'
mv $MV_PARAMS
```

What I want to actually execute is:

```
mv "foo 1" "foo 2"
```

But it doesn't seem to work. trying this:

```
mv "$MV_PARAMS"
```

Doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you should do is use an array:

```
mv_params=("foo 1" "foo 2")
mv "${mv_params[@]}"
```

The array expansion will properly handle array elements with whitespace or special characters.

Comment: Avoid using ALL_CAPS_VARS: [one day you'll use `PATH`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path) and wonder why your script is broken

Comment: Thanx, that worked too! Now I have to decide which is better... And I won't use all caps vars; for some reason I had the impression that script variables are usually all caps.

Answer (score 4):

Dealing with whitespace in filenames in shell scripts is often complicated.  In this case, given:

```
MV_PARAMS='"foo 1" "foo 2"'
```

When you write:

```
mv $MV_PARAMS
```

You end up with the shell running `mv` like this:

```
execve("/usr/bin/mv", ["mv", "\"foo", "1\"", "\"foo", "2\""])
```

That is, with four arguments:

- "foo
- 1"
- "foo
- 2"

You can use the `eval` command to have the shell parse the generated command line:

```
eval "mv $MV_PARAMS"
```

Which will do what you want.  Using `eval` can sometimes be tricky, and in situations in which `eval` seems to be the solution, I will often try to rewrite things to avoid requiring it.

Comment: It worked, Thanx!